# data.table into nested list

Tags: r, list, data.table, nested-lists

I have a data.table as follows,

```r
## install.packages(c("gapminder", "data.table"))
library(gapminder)
library(data.table)
gapminder <- data.table(gapminder)
my_table <- gapminder[, .(mdl = .(lm(lifeExp ~ pop + gdpPercap, 
                                  data = gapminder))), 
                          by = .(country, continent)]
```

The resulting table will be,

```
                country continent  mdl
  1:        Afghanistan      Asia <lm>
  2:            Albania    Europe <lm>
  3:            Algeria    Africa <lm>
  4:             Angola    Africa <lm>
  5:          Argentina  Americas <lm>
 ---                                  
138:            Vietnam      Asia <lm>
139: West Bank and Gaza      Asia <lm>
140:        Yemen, Rep.      Asia <lm>
141:             Zambia    Africa <lm>
142:           Zimbabwe    Africa <lm>
```

Now I want to get a list out of this data.table such that `mdl` should lie within each `country` which itself is nested within `continent`.

I have tried to get the result as,

```r
first_list <- split(my_table, my_table$continent)
second_list <- lapply(first_list, function(x){ 
                   split(x[, country := as.character(country)], x$country)
               })
final_list <- sapply(second_list, function(x) sapply(x, function(y) y$mdl))
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: You should read `?split.data.table` also check examples there. `split` data.table method can produce nested lists. Be sure to update as `split.data.table` was introduced in v1.9.8. It is OK to self-answer SO question.

Comment: @jangorecki Please post an answer. I'm curious how to do this and couldn't figure it out, only getting as far as `split(my_tab, by=c("continent", "country"), keep.by = FALSE, flatten = FALSE)` where `my_tab` is the table modified to have char columns instead of factors (since the latter throws an error apparently related to column restrictions of `dogroups`).

Comment: @Frank thanks for info, will look into it

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37335072/

Comment: @Frank I've filled [#1954](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1954), after convert to character process fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the nested list you are looking for with this kind of code :

```
    res<-lapply(unique(my_table$continent),
function(x){lapply(unique(my_table[continent==x]$country),
function(z){my_table[continent==x&country==z]})})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`data.tree`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) package:

```
library(data.tree)
# create a path string
my_table$pathString <- paste("world", my_table$continent, my_table$country, sep = "/")

# convert the data.table to nodes and nested lists
nested_list <- as.list(as.Node(my_table[, .(pathString, mdl)]))

# query the result
nested_list[["Asia"]][["Vietnam"]]

#$mdl
#$mdl[[1]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = lifeExp ~ pop + gdpPercap, data = gapminder)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          pop    gdpPercap  
#  5.365e+01    9.728e-09    7.676e-04
```

Or another option:

```
nested_list <- lapply(split(my_table, by = "continent"), 
                      function(dt) setNames(dt$mdl, dt$country))

nested_list[["Asia"]][["Vietnam"]]

#Call:
#lm(formula = lifeExp ~ pop + gdpPercap, data = gapminder)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          pop    gdpPercap  
#  5.365e+01    9.728e-09    7.676e-04
```

Comment: Is there a way to elegantly avoid having the double nesting `$mdl[[1]]` ?

Comment: @Frank. It seemed to not avoidable as the mdl column is by itself objects. If the column is a simply vector, it can be reduced to `$mdl`.